# Как задать дочернему блоку высоту 100%?

Tags: css

Есть родительский блок `.wrapper`, у которого задана минимальная высота 100%.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">Контент</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать для блока `.inner` также минимальную высоту 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Надо понимать что такое 100% и от чего вы их берете... 100% от необъявленой велечины = необъявленная величина. Это так не работает. Как вориант решения, можно написать так.

```css
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">Контент</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Блочные элементы (к которым по умолчанию относятся `<div>`, `<body>`, `<html>` и др.) имеют свойство растягиваться по ширине на 100%, а по высоте подстраиваться под содержимое.

Пройдём в вашем коде от самого вложенного элемента к корневому, т.е. снизу вверх:

```css
html {
  /* 
    А этому блоку совсем ничего не задано, т.е. 
    цепочка наследования размеров обрывается
  = подстраиваем высоту под контент
  = всего одна строчка текста 
  */
}

body {
  /* 
    В этом блоке только блок .wrapper
  + высота указана, но 100% от чего? 
  = подстраиваем высоту под размер блока .wrapper
  */
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  /* 
    В этом блоке только блок .inner
  + не указана высота 
  = подстраиваем высоту под размер блока .inner
  */
  min-height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  /* 
    В этом блоке всего одна строчка текста 
  + не указана высота 
  = подстраиваем высоту под размер текста 
  */
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">Контент</div>
</div>
```

Если бы была указана высота для `<html>` в 100%, то она соответствовала бы видимой части документа (читай, высоте окна), которая имеет вполне себе фиксированные размеры.

Также следует учитывать, что *min-* и *max-* - это, так скажем, "ограничители" и нежелательно заменять ими явное указание размеров (независимо от того, относительные они или абсолютные).

Итак, только тег `<html>` со значением 100% хоть что-то знает об истинном размере, отталкиваясь от высоты окна.

Теперь снова пройдёмся по иерархии и на каждом элементе зададим себе вопрос: "100% от чего? От какого значения?"

```css
html {
  height: 100%; /* 100% от высоты окна */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #f00;
}

body {
  height: 100%; /* 100% от высоты html */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fa0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* 100% от высоты body */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #090;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 100%; /* 100% от высоты .wrapper */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">Контент</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А разве имеет смысл ставить min-height:100%? Это же тоже самое что и height: 100%

Comment: @Arcadiy, Вы видимо невнимательно прочитали ответ. min-height - ограничивает, а height - задаёт размер. Допустим height будет меньше, чем 100%, тогда min-height не даст этого сделать. Но, это при условии, что height есть от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: min-heght:100% и height:100% по факту дадут одну и туже высоту, я именно писал про эти значения, про 100%

Comment: @Arcadiy, про какой элемент Вы говорите?

Comment: автор не понимает, что min-height:100% не ставят, так как больше 100% высота быть не может,  и тогда ставят значения в пикселях

Comment: @Arcadiy, как это не может быть больше 100% ? о_0

Comment: почитайте правильный ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341821/height100-vs-min-height100

Comment: @Arcadiy, ответ там правильный. Вот только контекст вопроса абсолютно другой. В том вопросе не уточняется, какие размеры у родителя проблемного блока, ибо вопрос про отличия свойств. А в текущем вопросе проблема именно в том, что совсем не указаны родители с размерами от которых идёт отсчёт.